# Flutter use api and webhook

Tags: flutter, api, dart, webhooks, flutter-http

i wanna work with this api in my flutter app
https://dev.chargily.com/docs/epay-api/
i have done the first part 1.Make Payment
but the second part 2. Payment confirmation i don't know how to do it because it contain webhook
(i wanna get the response sent via webhook_url)

this is the first part 1. Make Payment

```
final response = await dio
              .post(
            'http://epay.chargily.com.dz/api/invoice',
            options: Options(headers: {
              'X-Authorization':
                  '["API-KEY"]',
              'Accept': 'application/json',
            }),
            data: jsonEncode(params),
          )
              .then((value) async {
            log(value.data['checkout_url']);
            var url = await value.data['checkout_url'];
```

work perfectly
i need the second part 2. Payment confirmation

Comment: This should be a server side component; you can't expose a URL on your phone for this service to call. So your flutter app sohuld call your web service (hosted somewhere in the cloud), this service calls payment gateway and receives a call back through the callback. And then you need to notify somehow your phone app - your app could check every few seconds if the payment was completed for example.

Answer (score 0):

Webhooks are a fancy word to describe a server calling another server's Web Api Endpoint. so, it's not meant to be used in the frontend.
you can't verify / get payment confirmation directly from a flutter app, you have to host your own backend / serverless function to act as a webhook and report back to the frontend environment.